# DataSource WriteXML printing child rows for associate parent

Tags: c#, dataset, writexml

In my database, I have a parent and child tables.
For example, parent table contains last name and address, and child table contains last and first name.
There is a foreign key, so that a row in child table must have corresponding last-name in parent table.

When I read those two tables using 2 DataAdapter's, and add those DataTable's to DataSet, I'd like to print XML, that looks like this:

```
<parent_table>
  <last_name>Smith</last_name>
  <address>111 Hi Street, Bye city</address>
  <child_table>
    <last_name>Smith</last_name>
    <first_name>Ann</first_name>
  </child_table>
  <child_table>
    <last_name>Smith</last_name>
    <first_name>Bob</first_name>
  </child_table>
</parent_table>
```

However, at present I'm getting two tables printed separately:

```
<parent_table>
  <last_name>Smith</last_name>
  <address>111 Hi Street, Bye city</address>
</parent_table>
<child_table>
  <last_name>Smith</last_name>
  <first_name>Ann</first_name>
</child_table>
<child_table>
  <last_name>Smith</last_name>
  <first_name>Bob</first_name>
</child_table>
```

Is there a way to achieve (hopefully using DataSet.WriteXML()) my desired output?

I tried adding ForeignKeyConstraint, and tried adding DataRelation, but neither changed the output.

Disclaimer: the above was hand-written, so please excuse if there's an error in XML. The actual tables contain better foreign key than 'last-name'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Writing [DataSet Contents as XML Data (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx8h06sz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> When writing an XML representation of a DataSet that contains
>   DataRelation objects, you will most likely want the resulting XML to
>   have the child rows of each relation nested within their related
>   parent elements. To accomplish this, set the Nested property of the
>   DataRelation to true when you add the DataRelation to the DataSet. For
>   more information, see [Nesting DataRelations (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sfkwf9s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).